# Javascript html not displaying input

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I run this code on my webpage, I am unable to get the buttons to  perform an event upon being clicked. Nothing happens. I am wanting to display the user input for full name, date of birth and gender into the textbox whenever the user clicks display. If the user clicks next, the current data should be saved to the correct array and when the user clicks clear the current innput in the text boxes and the data in the array should be deleted. What do I need to adjust to make this happen?

```
<html>
<head>
<script language = "javascript">

var full_name;
var dob;
var gender;  
var nameList = new Array();  
var dateList = new Array();
var genderList = new Array();
function displayMembers() {
      var str = " ";
    var listLength = nameList.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
            document.memberForm.textArea.nameList[i];
            document.memberForm.textArea.dateList[i];
            document.memberForm.textArea.genderList[i];
    }
}

function saveMember() {
    nametemp = document.getElementByName("full_name");
    nameList.push(nametemp[0].value);

    datetemp = document.getElementByName("dob");
    dateList.push(datetemp[0].value;

    gendertemp = document.getElementByName("gender");
    genderList.push(gendertemp[0].value);
 }

 function clearList() {
    nameList= [];
    dateList = [];
    genderList = [];
 }
 </script>

 <title>INTERNET TECHNOLOGIES CLUB MEMBER LIST </title>
 <title>INTERNET TECHNOLOGIES CLUB MEMBER LIST </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form name = "memberForm">
 <h1>
 INTERNET TECHNOLOGIES CLUB MEMBER LIST
 </h1>

 Full Name: <input type = "text" name = "full_name" value = ""/>
 Date of Birth: <input type = "text" name ="dob" value = ""/>
 <br>
 Gender: <input type = "text" name = "gender" value = ""/>
 <br>
 <textarea name = "textBox" rows = "10" cols = "70">
 </textarea>
  <br>
 <input type = "button" value = "NEXT" onclick = document.memberForm.
  saveMember()"></button>
 <input type = "button" value = "DISPLAY" onclick          =document.memeberForm.textBox.write.Full Name Date of Birth   Gender      "displayMembers()">
 </button>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are there any error messages in the error console? Have you done some debugging to see where the code fails? The very simplest way to start doing that is "caveman debugging" -  a bunch of `alert()`s outputting variable values etc. to trace how the code proceeds and where things go wrong.

Comment: Start debugging your code in Chrome browsers' DevTools. Press `F12` on your webpage and [use the console tab] (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/). You can there are some very simple errors in there

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more problems I'm not seeing but here you have an unterminated string.

Change it to

```
 <input type="button" value="NEXT" onclick="document.memberForm.saveMember()"></button>
```

Comment: If i use this snippet of code, i get an error that says that the entire thing is not a function

Comment: you left a bracket on  `dateList.push(datetemp[0].value;`